# ¿Cómo abrir un objeto de indexedDB en una página distinta de la que fue creado?

Tags: javascript, html5, indexeddb

Según entiendo, `indexedDB` se inicia en una página, con algo más o menos como esto:

```
function startDB() {  
   var pagina = "otrapagina.html";     // Es la página a la que redirecciona  
   dataBase = indexedDB.open("MiColeccionDeObjetos", 1);  
   dataBase.onupgradeneeded = function (e) { 
    var active = dataBase.result;   // Crea el link con la DB, manejando su Result 
    var info = active.createObjectStore("NombreAlmacen", { keyPath : 'id', autoIncrement : true });  
    info.createIndex('NombreDelIndice', 'elIndiceACrear', { unique : false }); // Crea el índice
   };  
    dataBase.onsuccess = function (e) { 
        location.href = pagina; 
    };  
   dataBase.onerror = function (e)  { 
        // El_aviso_de_error 
   };  
}
```

Ahora lo que intento es abrir la base de datos en otra página, ¿cómo retomo esta base de datos de la primera página?

Answer (score 0):

**IndexedDB API** sigue la [política del mismo origen](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_del_mismo_origen). Esto quiere decir que solo puedes acceder a la misma `IndexedDB` desde páginas que tienen el mismo origen.

El *origen* viene definido por el protocolo, el dominio y el puerto.

```
http://www.ejemplo.com/pagina1.html
```

Donde:

- `http` es el protocolo
- `www.ejemplo.com` es el dominio
- y el puerto suponemos que es el `80` *(que es el puerto por defecto para http)*

En este caso se puede acceder al mismo `IndexedDB` desde `http://www.ejemplo.com/pagina2.html`.

Sin embargo, si intentamos acceder desde `https://www.ejemplo.com/pagina2.html` no nos lo permitirá, puesto que el protocolo es distinto `https` y el puerto también es distinto `443` *(es el puerto por defecto para https)*.

Comment: Ok, eso es justo lo que intento, creo `IndexedDB`en www.misitio.com/pagina1.html  y en www.misitio.com/pagina2.html quiero acceder al almacén creado, pero cuál sería el código?

Comment: El código sería exactamente el mismo en ambas páginas.

Comment: el problema era otro.
Mi duda es porque no he logrado abrir la DB en otra página, y al tratar de incluir un código para verificar, me aparece un error en el que el índice se marca como Undefined: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined"